# Empirical CDF of a sequence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Imagine I have a fixed sequence of non-negative real numbers $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. These are not i.i.d. random variables, but an arbitrary sequence.

For any $n$, I can define the empirical CDF function $F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} | i: x_i \leq x |.$

If the $x_i$ were i.i.d. drawn from a distribution with CDF F(x), then I would have that  $F_n(x)$ converges to $F(x)$ uniformly almost surely.

My question is, if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an arbitrary sequence, does the sequence of functions $F_n(x)$ converge to a limit $F(x)$? How should we interpret $F(x)?

Comment: In general the pointwise limit can exist and yet fail to be a valid CDF. Consider for instance $x_n=n$ for which the pointwise limit is $F \equiv 1$. Assuming a bounded sequence it seems likely that you are guaranteed to get a valid CDF as the pointwise limit, but it may be a bit weird: for instance for an increasing sequence, $x_n \leq \sup x_n$ always holds but $x_n \leq \sup x_n - \varepsilon$ fails for all but finitely many $n$, so you get convergence to the distribution that is concentrated at $\sup x_n$...even though $\sup x_n$ may never be attained.

Comment: Another interesting question is whether this depends on the permutation of the $x_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think the right approach is to assume that the $x_n$ are exchangeable and use DeFinetti's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Finetti%27s_theorem to argue that F(x) exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are sequences $\{x_n\}$ such that $F_n(x)$ fails to converge for most $x$, for pretty much the same reason that not all numbers are "normal".  The idea is to divide the integers into larger and larger consecutive blocks, such that each block spoils or overrules the effect of all earlier blocks.  Consider the case where  $x_n$ is the most significant digit of the decimal notation for $n$, given by a formula 
$$x_n = \lfloor 10^{ (\log_{10} (n)\bmod 1)} \rfloor,$$ the $F_n(x)$ values will oscillate.  The fraction of number beginning with `9` between $1$ and $99999$ is $11111/99999 = 1/9$ but the fraction between $1$ and $199999$ is $11111/199999 \approx 1/18$, and so on.  In the same ranges the corresponding fractions of numbers whose lead digit is `1` are $11111/99999=1/9$ and $111111/199999\approx10/18$.  So along one subsequence $F_n(9)$ has limit $1/18$ and along another it has limit $1/9$. 
 Similarly for other $x$ values, except those outside the range $1\le x \le 9$.

I'm sure there are easy-to-construct examples where this oscillation happens for each $x$.